# booting stops at "[OK] Reached Target Graphical Interface" after uninstalling NVidia drivers

Tags: opensuse

I've installed drivers from nVidia Graphics Drivers repo in OpenSuse 13.1. The drivers didn't work well so I've uninstalled them. After this X-Windows would not start at all, with the last message:

```
[OK] Reached Target Graphical Interface
```

What happened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the same problem as with ATI drivers, as discussed on OpenSuse forum 2 years ago:

[ATI Driver installs have destroyed SUSE/GNOME graphics setup](http://forums.opensuse.org/showthread.php/460174-ATI-Driver-installs-have-destroyed-SUSE-GNOME-graphics-setup/page2)

Uninstalling RPMs doesn't revert changes made during installation and leaves system with:

1. symlink `/var/lib/X11/X` pointing to nonexistent `/usr/bin/X.x11-video-nvidiaG03` (it should be reverted to point to `/usr/bin/Xorg`)
2. changed `DISPLAYMANAGER_XSERVER` value in `/etc/sysconfig/displaymanager` (it should be changed back to `Xorg`)

*(The link above has more details. But it took me a couple of hours of reading logs, rebooting and googling to find it. Maybe this Q&A will save someone's time).*

Comment: can you accept your own answer, so that this question doesn't show up as unanswered anymore :)? Thanks